# Limiting and sorting knockout.js foreach items

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0

i am really new knockout.js. what i am trying to achive is limiting foreach item. here it is my source :

```
<div data-bind="foreach: news">
      <!-- ko if: catId === '4' -->
            <div  class="news-item">
                <a data-bind="attr: { href: url, title: title }">
                   <div class="news-header-text" data-bind="text: title"></div>
                 </a>
                 <div class="news-date" data-bind="text: date" /></div>

            </div>
      <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

this is my javascript :

```
 (function()
        { // Wrap in function to prevent accidental globals
            if(location.protocol != "data:")
            {
                $(window).bind('hashchange', function()
                {
                    window.parent.handleChildIframeUrlChange(location.hash)
                });
            }

            // Class to represent a row in the seat reservations grid
            function cebesEnNewsIndex(title, date, url, catId, hits)
            {
                var self = this;
                self.title = title;
                self.date = date;
                self.url = url;
                self.catId = catId;
                self.hits = hits;
            }

            // Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
            function cebesEnNewsIndexViewModel()
            {
                var self = this;


                // Non-editable catalog data - would come from the server

                // Editable data
                self.news = ko.observableArray([
                new cebesEnNewsIndex("Welcome to Cebes Enterprise", "18 Mey 2012", "#", '4', '20'),
                new cebesEnNewsIndex("Groove for Dummies", "20 Mey 2012", "#", "4", "21"),
                new cebesEnNewsIndex("New Features of Cebes Framework", "18 Mey 2012", "#", "3", "19"),
                new cebesEnNewsIndex("Welcome to Cebes Enterprise", "20 Mey 2012", "#", "3", "24"),
                new cebesEnNewsIndex("Welcome to Cebes Enterprise sdfadfa", "18 Mey 2012", "#", '4', '20'),
                new cebesEnNewsIndex("Groove for Dummiessdfadf", "20 Mey 2012", "#", "4", "21"),
                new cebesEnNewsIndex("New Features of Cebes Frameworksdfad", "18 Mey 2012", "#", "3", "19"),
                new cebesEnNewsIndex("Welcome to Cebes Enterprisdfadfe", "20 Mey 2012", "#", "3", "24"),
                new cebesEnNewsIndex("Welcome to Cebes Enterprissdfadfe", "18 Mey 2012", "#", '4', '20'),
                new cebesEnNewsIndex("Groove for Dummiesdfads", "20 Mey 2012", "#", "4", "21"),
                new cebesEnNewsIndex("New Features of Cebes Framework", "18 Mey 2012", "#", "3", "19"),
                new cebesEnNewsIndex("Welcome to Cebesasdfa Enterprise", "20 Mey 2012", "#", "3", "24"),
                new cebesEnNewsIndex("Welcome to Cebessdfad Enterprise", "18 Mey 2012", "#", '4', '20'),
                new cebesEnNewsIndex("Groove fsdfaor Dummies", "20 Mey 2012", "#", "4", "21"),
                new cebesEnNewsIndex("New Featuresadfas of Cebes Framework", "18 Mey 2012", "#", "3", "19"),
                new cebesEnNewsIndex("Welcome tosdfad Cebes Enterprise", "20 Mey 2012", "#", "3", "24"),
                new cebesEnNewsIndex("New Emsfadfployee", "22 Mey 2012", "#", "5", "25")
                ]);


            }


            ko.applyBindings(new cebesEnNewsIndexViewModel());
        })();
```

as you can see on the fiddler, filtering works and displaying  8 news items

i want to limit the number and sort the number based on the dates items with the same data becoming like this (displaying only 3 filtered and sorted news items):

http://jsfiddle.net/2Ffqn/

here it is jsfiddle link of my script : http://jsfiddle.net/StRa6/
to keep it simple and please edit and save my jsfiddle.
any suggestion are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You should not place business logic in the view like that. A much better solution would be to create a filtered array using a `computed` observable, and bind to that.

```
self.selectedNews = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.news(), function(i) {
         return i.catId == 4; //Or, you know, whatever
       })
    });
```

Here is t[he fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/StRa6/2/).

Comment: Thank you tyrius for you advice, but you didn't show me yet how to limit foreach looping to specified number.

Comment: Um. Yes. Yes I did. Look at the fiddle. It's only displaying itmes with the `catId == 4` , like your examle. If that's not what you wanted, please post an example of your desired output.

Comment: You just completely changed what your question was.